# Using two Ruby classes with same name

Tags: ruby, jodatime, jruby

I'm using JRuby and working with dates.
The framework I'm in forces me to use both JodaTime's DateTime and Ruby's standard DateTime.

How do I handle them having the same name?

How do I refer to one when the other is also required?

Comment: Sounds as if you have both classes in the same namespace. You could assign JodaTime to a constant, i.e. `JT = org.joda.time` and reference it via `JT::DateTime`.

Comment: @Stefan This works. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to keep classes with the same name in different namespaces.

To avoid conflicts with Joda-Time's `DateTime`, you could assign the Java package to a constant:

```
require 'date'
require 'java'

JT = org.joda.time

JT::DateTime  # <- Joda-Time's DateTime
DateTime      # <- Ruby's DateTime
```